# Difficulty passing integer variables in struct.pack in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to pack two integer variables and write them to the serial port using struct.pack in Python. The variables are defined as integer variables but I keep getting the following error: 'struct.error: required argument is not an integer'

I have been successful at packing actual numbers, just not variables.

my code is

```
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
```

I assign integer values using a series of sliders I built in Tkinter and than call the command:

```
def Pace():

ser.write(struct.pack('!BB',var1,var2)
```

I'm sure I am missing something simple, but I can't seem to even force the variables to become integers with Int() or the equivalent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is `IntVar`? A class? A function? Does it possibly return `None`? Also, `B` is for `unsigned char`, `i` is for `int`. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) for details.

Comment: Use `get()` to get its content and `set()` to set it ([Reference](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm))

Answer (score 1):

`IntVar()` is not an integer - is a Tkinter object used to notifying observers when it's value changes.

To use it in struct pack you need to retrieve underlying primitive.
    struct.pack('!BB', var1.get(), var2.get())

[`.get()` method in docs (**emphasis mine**):](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

> The get method returns the current value of the variable, as a Python
>   object. For BooleanVar variables, the returned value is 0 for false,
>   and 1 for true. For DoubleVar variables, the returned value is a
>   Python float. **For IntVar, it’s an integer**. For StringVar, it’s either
>   an ASCII string or a Unicode string, depending on the contents.

Answer (score -1):

```
ser.write(struct.pack('!BB',var1.get(),var2.get())
```

I think at least ... maybe its just `var1(),var2()` ... its been a while since i messed with tkinter